# Make a div droppable after element is dragged out

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, droppable

This Seating Chart view shows a grid of "seats". Most of them begin with a student already inside. Those seats do not begin with the "droppable-item" class because I don't want the user to drop a student into an already-occupied seat. As soon as the user drags a student out of the seat, that seat should become droppable.

I'm also struggling with removing the droppable class from the new seat, but that might need to be a different question.

All of the solutions that I've read suggest that I destroy the original droppable. But that doesn't seem to apply here, because this view includes a dozen droppables.

The code below includes my attempt to make this work. The old seat does acquire the "droppable-item" *class* like it's supposed to, but does not seem to accept any students.

**seminars.coffee**

```
ready = ->
    currSeating = $('.tyrion').val().split(" ")

    $('.draggable-item').draggable
        stack: '.droppable-item'
        stack: '.draggable-item'
        start: (event, ui) ->
            console.log($(this).parent().attr("id"))
            seat = $(this).closest(".seat").attr("id")-1000;
            currSeating[seat] = 0
            $(this).parent().addClass("droppable-item")
            $(this).parent().droppable
                 #I've tried placing all of the droppable function lines here too. But I'm sure that isn't the correct approach.


    $('.droppable-item').droppable
        drop: (event, ui) ->
            justdragged = $(ui.draggable) 
            kid = justdragged.attr("id")
            seat = $(this).attr("id")-1000
            currSeating[seat] = kid
            $('.tyrion').val(currSeating)
            $(this).append(justdragged.removeAttr('style'))
            $(this).removeClass("droppable-item")

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

**seatingChart.html.erb**

```
<% def makeARow(group) %>
    <div class="row">
        <% group.each do |eyedee| %>
            <% if eyedee and eyedee.to_i > 0 %>
                <div class = "col-md-2 seat" id="<%= @counter %>">
                    <% student = Student.find(eyedee) %>
                    <div class="draggable-item" id="<%= student.id %>">
                        <li id="<%= student.id %>" >
                            <%= "#{student.firstPlusInit}" %>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% else %>
                <div class = "col-md-2 seat droppable-item" id="<%= @counter %>">
                </div>
            <% end %>
            <% @counter = @counter += 1 %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>


<div class = "container-fluid">
    <% @counter = 1000 %>
    <% @seminar.seating.in_groups_of(6).each do |group| %>
        <% makeARow(group) %>
    <% end %>
    <% newgroup = [0,0,0,0,0,0] %>
    <% makeARow(newgroup) %>
</div>
```

The line

console.log($(this).parent().attr("id"))

is me trying to debug and see whether the old seat can become the parent div for students. But none of the originally-occupied seats can ever be logged to the console through this line. Only the seats that were empty upon page load.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to resolve this problem, I realized that a better approach would be to create a "Temporary Staging Area" that isn't a seat. When the user drops a student onto an already-occupied seat, the old student is moved to the staging area.

I never did figure out how to make the divs droppable after page load, but now I no longer need that functionality. Seems like something that somebody else will need someday.